# Strange behavior of Git network graph

Tags: git, svn, github, merge

We recently migrated from SVN to Git (using Github enterprise) and gave our developers permission to push into master so they can merge back and forth. After just one day of work, things started to look strange. Each merge from master to any branch has an unreasonable amount of conflicts, as if the branches didn't know how to apply some changes. We are basically stuck in a situation where we can't merge any feature branch back into master because of that.

The github network graph looks very odd as well:

[image: strange network graph]

We don't understand why some of the branches are broken, particularly master. It looks like the breaks happen when a developer did a merge from master and then they are "fixed" when the branch is merged back in master. We are wondering if that's the cause of the numerous conflicts.

As a test, we created a new repository from a pre-mess snapshot and tried to do a merge from/to master and the graph looks fine. So there must be something wrong with what some of the developers have done.

I am thinking we should limit push permission to a few developers and use fork/pull requests to make changes but that leaves us with 2 days of unmerged work and a messed up master.

Does anybody have any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: It's probably missing/faulty merge information from the pre-git days in your Subversion directory

Comment: Do you think there is a way to find out where that got messed up? And could we fix it by rebasing that SVN commit?

Comment: Such messing up happens when a svn branch is created from a subdirectory of `trunk` (or any other branch) only. It's difficult to fix. Sometimes _grafts_ can help